# IOS Webview and video

Tags: ios, webview, video-streaming

I have a webview in an IOS app that I am loading with local data. The html page includes a link to stream a video.

Clicking on the link displays the video fine, but when the video terminates, the web view page does not reappear, instead the QTime viewer is still showing with the Play arrow. How can I make sure the webview reappears?

Comment: I have the same problem on iOS.But when I navigate to another page and return to the video page, then open the video and return, the problem's gone.Its pretty wired.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i faced the same problem in Webkit but not on iOS, on some other platform, the reason is as follow, 
1 -- When there is a stream content , video content, it will invokes the QTime plugin to display it, 
2 -- QTime will occupy entire screen to launch the video,
3 -- Please check if you could capture the Video End Event in your application, in such a case, there will be global instance of QTime plug-in, that you can hide and can display the Web-View.